# get rid of white strip across UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

I am have researched this and still cant figure out what the proper word for the white gloss strip across UITabBar. I have googled so much on how to remove this gloss and couldn't find anything. For a reference to what I am talking about, see this Image:

[image: Image of TabBar]

I really hope I am missing something simple here and am not over thinking this...

Thank you in advance for any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if any of this code helps you. This can all be found in Apple Docs. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
// custom icons
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
item.title = @"foo";
// setting custom images prevents the OS from applying a tint color
[item setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1_active.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1_image_deselected.png"]];
tab1ViewController.tabBarItem = item;

// tab bar

// set background image - will be used instead of glossy black
tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_bg.png"];
// optionally set the tint color - setting this ti nil will result in the standard, blue tint color. tint color is ignored when custom icons are set as above.
tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = nil;
// remove the highlight around the selected tab - or provide an alternate highlight image. If you don't do this the iOS default is to draw a highlighted box beneath the selected tab icon.
tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just give the UITabBar a custom background view (`backgroundImage`).

The gloss is there only when you use a default style or tint. If you set the `backgroundImage`, the gloss is taken away and the whole thing is left up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just customise the tab bar and all will fix. If need can send you some source code :)